# Overlapping 2 transparent Texture2Ds in OpenGL ES

Tags: ipad, opengl-es, texture2d, blending

I'm trying to make a 2D game for the iPad with OpenGL.  I'm new to OpenGL in general so this blending stuff is new.

My drawing code looks like this:

```
static CGFloat r=0;
r+=2.5;
r=remainder(r, 360);

glLoadIdentity();
//you can ignore the rotating and scaling
glRotatef(90, 0,0, -1);
glScalef(1, -1, 1);
glTranslatef(-1024, -768, 0);

glClearColor(0.3,0.8,1, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_ONE,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

[texture drawInRect:CGRectMake(512-54, abs(sin(((r+45)/180)*3.14)*500), 108, 108)];
[texture drawInRect:CGRectMake(512-54, abs(sin((r/180)*3.14)*500), 108, 108)];
```

("texture" is a Texture2D that has a transparent background)
All I need to know how to do is make it so that a blue box around the texture doesnt cover up the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to open up the texture image in your favourite image editor and set the blue area to be 0% opaque (i.e. 0) in the alpha channel. The `SRC_ALPHA` part of `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` means the alpha value in the source texture.

Chances are you're using 32-bit colour, in which case you'll have four channels, 8 bits for Red, Green, Blue and Alpha.

Comment: I'm 100% sure the image (http://i55.tinypic.com/34rsv9l.png) is fully transparent.

Comment: You said I'm probably using 32-bit color.  Would that affect anything?

Comment: Nah, 32 bit should be good. You said you're seeing blue, do you mean you're seeing your background blue colour in the bits that should be transparent over the other one? If that's the case I suspect it's your draw order. With transparency you need to render the farthest polys first, so when the new transparent areas are being blended with the background the ones behind are already in the frame buffer, otherwise you it'll blend with the background, then you draw the other one behind but it gets obscured by the areas which should be transparent.

Comment: "you're seeing your background blue colour in the bits that should be transparent over the other one?" Is correct.  But I want the textures to overlap, and they're the same texture so how would I make the transparency show through to the texture underneath?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just a case of the order in which you're rendering your polys. Do a test where they overlap and ensure you draw the one farthest from the camera before the other, I think you'll get the result you're looking for.

Comment: It's 2D... aren't they all equally close to the camera?